# Use JSONP to load an html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying to load an external page using `JSONP`, but the page is an `HTML` page, I just want to grab the contents of it using ajax.

EDIT: The reason why I'm doing this is because I want to pass all the user information ex: headers, ip, agent, when loading the page rather than my servers.

Is this doable? Right now, I can get the page, but jsonp attempts to parse the json, returning an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Sample code:

```
$.post('http://example.com',function(data){
    $('.results').html(data);
},'jsonp');
```

I've set up a jsfiddle for people to test with:
http://jsfiddle.net/8A63A/1/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#Script_element_injection

> Making a JSONP call (in other words, to employ this usage pattern),
>   requires a script element. Therefore, for each new JSONP request, the
>   browser must add (or reuse) a new  element—in other words,
>   inject the element—into the HTML DOM, with the desired value for the
>   "src" attribute. This element is then evaluated, the src URL is
>   retrieved, and the response JSON is evaluated.

Now look at your error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

`<` is the first character of any html tag, probably this is the start of `<DOCTYPE`, in this case, which is, *of course*, invalid JavaScript.

And **NO**, you can't use JSONP for fetching html data.

Comment: If I'm able to retrieve the data, why am I not able to change how that data is interpreted?

Comment: Because you loaded it as a content of `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 12):

I have done what you want but in my case I have control of the server side code that returns the HTML.
So, what I did was wrapped the HTML code in one of the Json properties of the returned object and used it at client side, something like:

```
callback({"page": "<html>...</html>"})
```

The Syntax error you are facing it's because the library you're using expects json but the response is HTML, just that.

Answer (score 2):

I've got three words for you: [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Unless the remote URL actually supports proper JSONP requests, you won't be able to do what you're trying to. And that's a good thing.

Edit: You could of course try to proxy the request through your server …

Comment: is it a good thing? it's archaic and forces benevolent forces to use work arounds like JSONP. Instead of a universal ban on cross origin scripting, there should be something more fluid and dynamic, something like : Cross Origin Resource Sharing http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Comment: The fact that the page is being pulled says that it can be pulled without parsing as json.

Comment: There sure are better alternatives. For the time being though, SOP prevents every script-kiddie-SQL-injection-pwned website you run across from posting "I just bought a penis pump, lololol" on your FB timeline.

Comment: Korvin, what do you mean, the page is being pulled?

Comment: It is very interesting, with a type of JSONP the page is fetched, the problem is that the response is not valid JSON hence the syntax Error.

Answer (score 2):

If you really just want to employ the client to snag an HTML file, I suggest using flyJSONP - which uses YQL.. or use jankyPOST which uses some sweet techniques:

jankyPOST creates a hidden iframe and stuffs it with a form (iframe[0].contentWindow.document.body.form.name).

Then it uses HTML5 (watch legacy browsers!) webMessaging API to post to the other iframe and sets iframe's form elements' vals to what u specified.

Submits form to remote server...done.

Or you could just use PHP curl, parse it, echo it, so on.

IDK if what exactly ur using it for but I hope this helps.

ALSO...
I'm pretty sure you can JSONP anything that is an output from server code.  I did this with ClientLogin by just JSONPing their keyGen page and successfully consoleLogged the text even though it was b/w tags.  I had some other errors on that but point is that I scraped that output.

Currently, I'm trying to do what you are so I'll post back if successful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. JSONP requires that the response is rendered properly.

If you want another solution, what about loading the url in an iframe and trying to talk through the iframe. I'm not 100% positive it will work, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score -2):

First, call the AJAX URL manually and see of the resulting HTML makes sense.

Second, you need to close your DIV in your fiddle example.

Comment: Won't work because `Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.