# Integrating OAuth workflow in mobile version of site

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

We have following workflow for services like twitter and facebook:

1. User clicks "Post" button.
2. We obtain auth url on server
3. We send to client auth url
4. Client opens auth url in **standard javascript popup window**
5. Client authorizes and returns by callback url
6. On callback url we interacting with social service.

We have big troubles with step 4 on mobile phones.

Standard javascript popups not working on mobile. What alternatives we can use for external auth urls?

**UPD** Temporary solution is to generate auth links as anchors and place them in document. 
It solves problem, but we want better UX.

Comment: is this MVC4? Can you remove the js and use the standard browser post back

Comment: @CR41G14 It's not MVC4. I can use postback, but it's last step - too much changes required.

Comment: @NikolayFominyh by standard javascript popup window you are saying the alert box rite?

Comment: @SathyaRaj, nope. I mean  `widnow.open()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using [jquery mobile popup](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/) for this mobile sites and it also look perfect desktop browser also. I hope you use callback like these(well i use something like this)

```
var jsonp = document.createElement("script");
        jsonp.type = "text/javascript";
        jsonp.src = "http://foo.com/api/ad?foo_var=4345&callback=displayinfo";
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(jsonp);
```

In the callback function you can use those popup like

```
function displayinfo(data) {    
$("#somepopup").html('<div data-role="popup">
                        '+data+'
                    <div id="ok" data-inline=true data-role=button>
                        <a class="ui-link-inherit" href="">Ok</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="cancel" data-inline=true data-role=button>
                        <a class="ui-link-inherit" href="">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>');

                $('#ok').button();
                $('#cancel').button();

                $("#somepopup").popup();
}
```

you should have a div with id somepopup in your document and all this works fine if you implement jquery mobile. I hope this helps.

Comment: Good idea, but twitter returns HTML by auth url. And it can't be used in jsonp according to following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531823/use-jsonp-to-load-an-html-page

Comment: @NikolayFominyh i think twitter provides for everthing i use api from https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens and implementing those api would be like https://tutsplus.com/lesson/the-twitter-api/ ,but then also the implementation  would entirely depend upon the project.

Comment: In these links - no word, about obtaining token from mobile. I mean, there are general rules, that will lead to solution, that don't have good UX. However, looks like there are no good solution around for this problem.