# How Submit Form Without Refreshing A page which doesnt have any input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, php-curl

I already have everything pre-defined in the script. What I want to do is when I click on **SUBMIT** it will do the work without refreshing the page. Currently it refreshes the page and shows "Working". What I am trying to do is something like this:

[image: Image link of how I want it to be]

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
$url="http://google.com";

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $ch = curl_init("$url");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if (200==$retcode) {
        echo "working";
    } else {
       echo "failed";
    }
}
?>

<form action='ping.php'  method='post'><input type="submit"   name="submit"></form>



<script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>



       <script type="text/javascript">
            var $url =  '<?php echo $url ?>';
            $('#submit').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);
        $.get($url,function(data){
            $this.text('Success');
        });
    });
                </script>
```

#### EDIT:

The script in the above example shows an error:

> [The request] has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

so I was going to do it with PHP cURL. If anyone knows any solution, please help.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Why are you loading two versions of jQuery?

Comment: @jessegavin forgot to remove it.Removed.

Comment: There is no element with id attribute 'submit' so the click handler (i.e. `$('#submit').click(function(e){...`) isn't getting called

Comment: CORS or Cross Origin Request Sharing (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS),  the browser makes a HTTP OPTIONS request before sending the actual form data. The data source / web app needs to respond with the Allow-Access-* set of headers to tell the browser it is OK to make a request with the wanted HTTP method to the desired resource. The easy work around: make the server respond with a 200 OK and the set of CORS headers to allow the form to submit to the server. PM if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

I am no PHP expert, but I think this line

```
var $url =  '<?php echo $url ?>';
```

will render to html as

```
var $url = 'http://google.com';
```

This means you're trying to do an XHR call to google's website from your own domain. This is why you're getting CORS errors.

I *think* you're actually trying to use PHP as a proxy to communicate with Google (which should work fine).

If the code you pasted above is named `ping.php`, then the action on the  `<form>` looks like it's wired up to POST to itself.

The only change you should need to make then is the following...

```
<form action='ping.php' method='post'>
  <button>PING</button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

  // Use the `submit` event on the form instead of the click event on the button. 
  // It's good practice for this sort of thing.

  $('form').on('submit', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();



    var form = $(this);
    var button = form.find('button');

    // Set the button text to 'working'
    button.text('Working...');

    var url = form.attr('action');
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      button.text('Success');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no javascript expert but when you try to make cross-domain calls, you should set the dataType to jsonp and crossDomain to true. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'HTTP://THE_URL',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
});
```

I could be wrong tough :)

Comment: The jsonp approach might be a good idea but the URL in the OPs code (i.e. `http://google.com`) returns HTML. "_NO, you can't use JSONP for fetching html data_" - from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7532400/1575353)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the *Access Control Allow Origin* error is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issue. That is happening because the AJAX request is pointed to the url in $url (i.e. `http://google.com`). Instead, use the curl request at the top of the code (i.e. `if(isset($_POST["submit"])){...`) by using [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) instead of [$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). The URL of the post should be the PHP page (i.e. pong.php?). In the code sample below and [demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/j3ua-6hx5) (see end of this answer) it uses [PHP_SELF](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.server-indices) (i.e `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`) for the url to send the POST request to. And it passes $url in the POST data (second parameter of [.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). Plus we need to use [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) to update the text of the button (see notes below).

```
var $url =  '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>';
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.post($url,{url: "<?php echo $url;?>"}, function(data){
        //see note below about using .text()
        //$this.text('Success');
        $this.val('Success');
     });
});
```

Also, as I mentioned in a comment, there is no element with id attribute *submit* so the click handler is never getting executed. And in order to update the text on the submit button, give it a value and update the value using [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/).

- Add the *id* and *value* attributes:

  ```
  <input type="submit" id="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit">
  ```
- Use [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) in the success callback:

  ```
   $this.val('Success');
  ```

See a demonstration in [this PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/j3ua-6hx5).

One other possible function that could be used is [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) - it would still be prone to the CORS issue but at least the [callback function](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) can be called.