# By what mechanism does AngularJS fetch remote partials?

Tags: angularjs

According to the doc, [$sceDelegateProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider) can be used to whitelist domains from which Angular may fetch partials hosted on a different domain than the app, to support such a route configuration:

```
$routeProvider.when('/test1/', {
  templateUrl: 'https://serverName.com/html/test1.html',
  controller: 'test1'
});
```

A [comment in the repo](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/301fdda648680d89ccab607c413a7ddede7b0165/src/ng/http.js#L880) (and a lack of imagination) lead to me to believe remote partials would be fetched via JSONP. Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: No. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531823/use-jsonp-to-load-an-html-page

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, @baao, one can fetch HTML via JSONP provided it is wrapped properly; e.g., `{html: "<p>Hello world!</p>"}`. In any case, I'm as interested in knowing what the mechanism is as what the mechanism isn't. Does anyone know? Thanks!